# finding exact string on data.frame

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to look for a string on a data frame with this code:

```
grep('of', df$term, fixed=TRUE )
```

but it returns "kind of" for example.

How can I get it to look only for the "of" word?
(it can be another code, doesn't have to be grep)

Thanks

Comment: you mean this `regmatches(df$term, gregexpr("of", df$term, fixed=T))` ?

Comment: @Diego, provide some of your data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you are after from the question. You want to match "of" but not "kind of"?

How about just using `==`? This returns a match only when the string is exactly equal to "of" - it should be more efficient than a regular expression based approach.

```
text <- c("of", "kind of", "often", "toff")
text == 'of'
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: yes that was the case, I had spaces, which were messing with my lookup. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this, using the `stringr` package?  There are certain to be other text possibilities, of course.

```
text <- c("of", "lots of", "often", "toff")
```

find in the text string where the pattern is at the start, has "of" and ends

```
str_detect(text, "^of$")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```